# P2P payment provider or API to allow users to buy and cash-out an in-app currency

Tags: api, online-payment, cryptocurrency

We are building a platform for content creators and we would like for them to be able to exchange content between each other and pay each other with our in-app currency. This in app currency is purchasable with their credit card and we would like for our platform to be international. Is there a payment method or an API we could use that allows our users to cash out their in-app currency for fiat currency and withdraw the funds to their bank account? Knowing that our in-app currency can be exchanged between users from different nationalities, they could have funds coming from all over the world that they would need to cash out in their home currency.

I hope this request is clear enough.

Thank you for your time, have a great day.